# Using webcam with Javascript to take snapshots

Tags: javascript

making a page to take snapshots with the webcam. but suddenly it stopped working on every computer. Did i make a typo i cant see myself, or does anyone has an idea too fix this??

- added the draw in bit aswell

  ```
  // Put event listeners into place
  window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
      // Grab elements, create settings, etc.
      var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas"),
          context = canvas.getContext("2d"),
          video = document.getElementById("video"),
          videoObj = { "video": true },
          image_format= "jpeg",
          jpeg_quality= 85,
          errBack = function(error) {
              console.log("Video capture error: ", error.code); 
          };


      // Put video listeners into place
      if(navigator.getUserMedia) { // Standard
          navigator.getUserMedia(videoObj, function(stream) {
              video.src = stream;
              video.play();
              $("#snap").show();
          }, errBack);
      } else if(navigator.webkitGetUserMedia) { // WebKit-prefixed
          navigator.webkitGetUserMedia(videoObj, function(stream){
              video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
              video.play();
              $("#snap").show();
          }, errBack);
      } else if(navigator.mozGetUserMedia) { // moz-prefixed
          navigator.mozGetUserMedia(videoObj, function(stream){
              video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
              video.play();
              $("#snap").show();
          }, errBack);
      }



  // Get-Save Snapshot - image 
      document.getElementById("snap").addEventListener("click", function() {
          context.drawImage(video, 0, 0, 640, 480);
          // the fade only works on firefox?
          $("#video").fadeOut("slow");
          $("#canvas").fadeIn("slow");
          $("#snap").hide();
          $("#reset").show();
          $("#upload").show();
  ```

Comment: console gives you any error?. IT used to work?

Comment: console just gives me "failed to load resource [media%20MediaStream] (not found)

Comment: yeah tbh it used to work, but only i chrome, yeez. any other ideas to make this is welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never draw your video to the canvas in this part of the code.

Also, `navigator.getUserMedia` is not the "*standard*" anymore, it has been updated to `navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia` which will return a Promise.

```js
var ctx = c.getContext('2d');
var vid = document.createElement('video');

vid.oncanplay = function() {
  c.width = this.videoWidth;
  c.height = this.videoHeight;
  draw();
}

navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
  video: true
}).then((stream) => {
  vid.srcObject = stream;
  vid.play();
});

function draw() {
  ctx.drawImage(vid, 0, 0);
  requestAnimationFrame(draw);
}
```

```html
<canvas id="c"></canvas>
```

And [a fiddle for chrome](https://jsfiddle.net/uj3ter8h/) since it doesn't allow gUM in SO-snippets.

Ps : if you need to support older implementations, check the official WebRTC polyfill, [adapter.js](https://github.com/webrtc/adapter)

Comment: i see what you mean and what works, but iam not sure how i implement it in my own code for now. ive made a fiddle with the full code.you mind taking a look? 
https://jsfiddle.net/7LknaL0e/

Comment: god o' god, king of kings, i salute you for removing my headache sir!

Comment: Kalido: you might also want to adopt
vid.srcObject = stream;
which is the shiny spec way to do things

Comment: @PhillipHancke you're right. I guess I didn't because [I was playing with Blobs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39874867/canvas-recording-using-capturestream-and-mediarecorder?noredirect=1#comment67037087_39874867) at the same time and that FF unfortunatwly only accepts MediaStream as srcObject...